# CSS3 Marquee animation troubles

Tags: css, marquee

I am making a stock ticker, it is going well but I am having a issue with my CSS.

The stock ticker has a marquee, it scrolls throughout but cannot complete one cycle. The stock ticker needs to be of a 2em hight (which it is) However because the list of stocks is quite extensive it is never getting a chance to reach the end, thus most of the stocks never come into sight.

I am pretty sure it is related to  css: animation: marquee 10s linear infinite; as the marquee is cutting short every 10 seconds. I have attached a jsfiddle so anyone of a generous nature can experiment.

```
 .box {

    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-family:"HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}
.floatleft2 {

    float:left;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-family:"HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.stockSymbolnew {
}
.stockWrapper {
    height: 2em;
    text-indent: -1000em;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-family:"HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}
.stockSymbol {
    font-weight: 600;
}
.stockPrice {
    font-weight: 600;
    color: red;
}
.stockChange {
    font-weight: 600;
    color: green;
}
.stockTime {
    font-weight: 600;
    color: grey;
    font-size: smaller;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
p {
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
.symbol {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
.symbol .name {
    display: block
}
.symbol.up {
    background: #70DB70
}
.symbol.up .change {
    color: green
}
.symbol.down {
    background: #f7cdc2
}
.symbol.down .change {
    color: red
}
#verticalScroller {
    position: absolute;
    width:268px;
    height: 2em;

    border: 0px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#verticalScroller > div {
    height: 2em;
    position:absolute;
    width:268px;
    border: 0px solid blue;
    overflow:hidden;
}
div.marquee > div > div > div:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #eee;
}
div.marquee > div > div > div {
    padding-right: 15px;
}
.container {
        height: 2em;
    margin: 1em auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: white;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.marquee {
height: 2em;
    top: 6em;
    position: relative;
       animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-delay: 2s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    animation: marquee 10s linear infinite;
}
.marquee:hover {
    animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes marquee {
    0% {
        top: 2em
    }
    100% {
        top: -11em
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/phbakdLe/1/

Regards
Sam

Answer (score 0):

The height of the content you want to display is bigger than 20em. If you change this value to 825px then all the stocks are displayed. After that, the time is not enough, 35s should work.

```
.marquee {
    top: 6em;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    animation: marquee 35s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes marquee {
    0% {
        top: 2em
    }
    100% {
        top: -825px
    }
}
```